# Asynchronously Api calls and returning data outside the block

Tags: objective-c, api, objective-c-blocks

I don't understand why I am getting null array outside the block code, even though I am using __block keyword on my array.

I am successfully getting data from a backend api with following code

```
`-(void)getJsonResponse:(NSString *)urlStr success:(void (^)(NSArray *responseDict))success failure:(void(^)(NSError* error))failure
{
    NSURLSession *session = [NSURLSession sharedSession];
    NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:urlStr];

    // Asynchronously API is hit here
    NSURLSessionDataTask *dataTask = [session dataTaskWithURL:url
                                            completionHandler:^(NSData *data, NSURLResponse *response, NSError *error) {
                                              //  NSLog(@"%@",data);
                                                if (error)
                                                    failure(error);
                                                else {
                                                    NSArray *json  = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data options:0 error:nil];
                                                   // NSLog(@"%@",json);
                                                    success(json);
                                                }
                                            }];
    [dataTask resume];    // Executed First
}`
```

Then in my function for returning the data I am using following

```
 `- (NSArray *)get_data:(NSDictionary *)credentials{

    NSString *urlStr =[ NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://test.com %@",credentials];
   __block NSArray *jsonArray= [[NSArray alloc]init];
    [self getJsonResponse:urlStr success:^(NSArray *responseArray) {
        jsonArray = responseArray;
        NSLog(@"%@",responseArray);
    } failure:^(NSError *error) {
        // error handling here ...
    }];
     NSLog(@"%@",jsonArray);
    return jsonArray;
}
`
```

The issue here is although I am successfully getting data within getJsonResponse block, but when I am trying to return the response data array as function return I am getting null for jsonArray. I thought assigning __block infront of jsonArray should retain the data assign within the block code ?

The second approach is not to use Async way like following

```
`- (NSData *)sendSynchronousRequest:(NSURLRequest *)request returningResponse:(NSURLResponse **)response error:(NSError **)error
{

    NSError __block *err = NULL;
    NSData __block *data;
    BOOL __block reqProcessed = false;
    NSURLResponse __block *resp;

    [[[NSURLSession sharedSession] dataTaskWithRequest:request completionHandler:^(NSData * _Nullable _data, NSURLResponse * _Nullable _response, NSError * _Nullable _error) {
        resp = _response;
        err = _error;
        data = _data;
        reqProcessed = true;
    }] resume];

    while (!reqProcessed) {
        [NSThread sleepForTimeInterval:0];
    }

    *response = resp;
    *error = err;
    return data;
}`
```

That way its blocking the main thread whilst waiting for data.

Comment: You cannot use a function with async request that way. Because there is a good chance that your async request is still waiting for the response before the `return jsonArray;` is called. The best approach is implement your function with `delegate` or callback block which will be called when response data is ready.

Comment: @RyanB I have updated my question with second approach where I am not using async request. But the second approach I am achieving the results but its blocking the main thread.

Comment: Your second attempt surely work but it blocks the main thread, hence isn't a good approach to do too.

Comment: @RyanB then I am out of ideas what would be best approach and stlll works

Comment: If you have started using `async` functions then you should use it everywhere. `get_data` should also be asynchronous.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would suggest using the same approach of `getJsonResponse` for your `get_data` function:

```
- (void)get_data:(NSDictionary *)credentials finish:(void(^)(NSArray *data))finish{

    NSString *urlStr =[ NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://test.com %@",credentials];
   __block NSArray *jsonArray= [[NSArray alloc]init];
    [self getJsonResponse:urlStr success:^(NSArray *responseArray) {
        jsonArray = responseArray;
        if (finish) {
            finish(jsonArray);
        }
    } failure:^(NSError *error) {
        // error handling here ...
    }];
}
```